# Windows Mobile Emulator For Linux

Tags: linux, windows-mobile, emulation

I was developing Windows Mobile applications on a Windows machine using C#, just to test the platform, but now I'm back to Linux and now developing for Windows CE on it([CeGCC](http://cegcc.sourceforge.net/) and [FPC](http://freepascal.org/)), but it's very boring to compile and send the executable to the device everytime just to do a simple test, then I want to know where can I find a good emulator for Linux to debug my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qemu is really nice and its open source.  You can also attach a debugger to Qemu to debug operating systems,  comes in handy if you are writing device drivers.   Using QEMU you can emulate other processor types such as ARM.   personally I use VMWare workstation unless i need to emulate another processor type.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your only bet is trying to run Microsoft's own emulator under Wine. This is the only ARM emulator you will find Windows Mobile images for. Search the web, some people had success with this approach - though the installation is tricky. Oh, and you won't get network working in the emulator, as this requires a special Windows device driver (which obviously won't work under Wine).

For this last reason, you may want to make a full desktop Windows (or possibly ReactOS) installation inside qemu, and install the PDA emulator inside the PC emulator.

And think how cool it would be to play Super Mario Bros inside a NES emulator inside a PDA emulator inside a PC emulator! :)))))